# How do I parse webserver log using R?

Tags: r, logging, webmin

which is the best way to parse a log file like this using R?

```
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:16:29 +0100] "POST /csw/servlet/cswservlet HTTP/1.1" 200 279
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:16:29 +0100] "GET /DescargaFenomenos/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 11769
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:16:29 +0100] "GET /IDEE-ServicesSearch/ServicesSearch.html?locale=es HTTP/1.1" 200 1665
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:16:29 +0100] "GET /search/indexLayout.jsp?PAGELANGUAGE=es HTTP/1.1" 200 9874
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:16:29 +0100] "GET /clientesIGN/wmsGenericClient/index.html?lang=ES HTTP/1.1" 200 12058
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:16:30 +0100] "POST /csw/servlet/cswservlet HTTP/1.1" 200 258038
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:09 +0100] "GET //DescargaFenomenos/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 11769
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:33 +0100] "GET //DescargaFenomenos/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 11769
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:33 +0100] "GET //show.do?to=pideep_pidee.ES HTTP/1.1" 200 26647
192.168.69.10, 62.97.81.202 - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:34 +0100] "POST /csw/?locale=es HTTP/1.0" 200 2536
192.168.69.10, 62.97.81.202 - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:34 +0100] "GET /DescargaFenomenos/index.jsp HTTP/1.0" 200 11769
192.168.69.10, 62.97.81.202 - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:34 +0100] "GET /clientesIGN/wmsGenericClient/index.html?lang=ES HTTP/1.0" 200 12058
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:39 +0100] "GET //csw/servlet/cswservlet?request=GetCapabilities&service=CSW&version=2.0.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 8867
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:46 +0100] "GET //csw/servlet/cswservlet?request=GetCapabilities&service=CSW&version=2.0.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 8867
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:18:10 +0100] "GET //show.do?to=pideep_pidee.ES HTTP/1.1" 200 26647
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:19:01 +0100] "GET //DescargaFenomenos/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 11769
```

I must consider border cases like having 2 IP's in a single line (internal and external).

Thanks!

Comment: A regular expression can probably be used to parse this, similar to what you would do in perl.  My question is, how do you want the data to look in the end?

Comment: Prepare to write bitchy regex. Tagged expressions and `gsub` are your friends.

Comment: If you want to make your life easier Apache has a very flexible way of specifying what the log files look like. This "Common Log" format is a pain since half the things are space-separated, the other half are delimited by square brackets, the other half are quoted, and the other half are comma-separated... It just doesn't add up. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html for how to reconfigure and make your logs sane (assumes access to the web server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this example it suffices to replace the leading dashes with two NA's and the commas with spaces. You can then parse with `read.table()`

```
datlog <- readLines(textConnection('- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:16:29 +0100] "POST /csw/servlet/cswservlet HTTP/1.1" 200 279
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:16:29 +0100] "GET /DescargaFenomenos/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 11769
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:16:29 +0100] "GET /IDEE-ServicesSearch/ServicesSearch.html?locale=es HTTP/1.1" 200 1665
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:16:29 +0100] "GET /search/indexLayout.jsp?PAGELANGUAGE=es HTTP/1.1" 200 9874
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:16:29 +0100] "GET /clientesIGN/wmsGenericClient/index.html?lang=ES HTTP/1.1" 200 12058
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:16:30 +0100] "POST /csw/servlet/cswservlet HTTP/1.1" 200 258038
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:09 +0100] "GET //DescargaFenomenos/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 11769
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:33 +0100] "GET //DescargaFenomenos/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 11769
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:33 +0100] "GET //show.do?to=pideep_pidee.ES HTTP/1.1" 200 26647
192.168.69.10, 62.97.81.202 - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:34 +0100] "POST /csw/?locale=es HTTP/1.0" 200 2536
192.168.69.10, 62.97.81.202 - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:34 +0100] "GET /DescargaFenomenos/index.jsp HTTP/1.0" 200 11769
192.168.69.10, 62.97.81.202 - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:34 +0100] "GET /clientesIGN/wmsGenericClient/index.html?lang=ES HTTP/1.0" 200 12058
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:39 +0100] "GET //csw/servlet/cswservlet?request=GetCapabilities&service=CSW&version=2.0.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 8867
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:17:46 +0100] "GET //csw/servlet/cswservlet?request=GetCapabilities&service=CSW&version=2.0.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 8867
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:18:10 +0100] "GET //show.do?to=pideep_pidee.ES HTTP/1.1" 200 26647
- - - [20/Nov/2011:01:19:01 +0100] "GET //DescargaFenomenos/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 11769'))
 datlog <- gsub("^-", "NA NA", datlog)
 datlog <- sub("\\,", "   ", datlog)
 datlog<-read.table(text=datlog, fill=TRUE)
 datlog
```

Spacedman asked about datetime parsing:

```
datlog[['dtime']] <- as.POSIXct( paste( sub("\\[", "", datlog[[5]]), 
                                         sub("\\]", "", datlog[[6]]) ),
                                 format="%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z")
```

Comment: Will that fail if there's a comma in the query? I don't think they are required to be escaped. Obviously there's still some work to do parsing the date.

Comment: If you mean the regex pattern, then I see that escaping is not necessary, but unlike many other unnecessay escapes, does not throw an error. The request for "parsing" is a bit on the vague side. One could also imagine wanting to extract information from the HTML requests.

Comment: No I mean a comma in the GET path. The log format is: dash or one or more comma space separated ip addresses, repeated three times, date in square brackets, quoted request, status code, size. Fiddly!

Comment: I see. It might damage the GET or POST initiated sequence, but it would not fail because of that. You could proably construct a regex pattern that would get "fenced" to the portion before the GET/POST event. If there were a maximum of 2 ids then you could use sub instead of gsub and I will change to that in the answer.Again ... parsing requires some notion of semantics and this has not been provided by the questioner.